# Save and Close Excel file generated by 2016 and now it's running on Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba

I've got problem with my VBA for Saving and Closing file so many times, it works sometimes and sometimes dont work. I use Task Scheduler for opening file and wait until 30 minutes to close and save file. Sometimes it asked me to debug the code on the line of

```
If wb.Name = GlobalBook.Name Then
```

Please let me if I had to update anything to make it work. Thank you.

Module 1 Code:

```
'Global variables
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 1800 ' seconds (set to 30 minutes)
Public Const cRunWhat = "SaveClose"  ' the name of the procedure to run
Public GlobalBook As Workbook

'Start Timer using interval set in global variables
Sub StartTimer()
    Set GlobalBook = ActiveWorkbook
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub

'Stop the Timer whenever the workbook is closed prematurely
Public Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=False
End Sub

'Close the workbook automatically once the Timer has expired
Public Sub SaveClose()
    'Time is up, workbook will save and close automatically
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        'Check to see if workbook is still open
        If wb.Name = GlobalBook.Name Then
            Set wb = Application.Workbooks(GlobalBook.Name)
            'Close workbook and Save Changes
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
        Next
End Sub
```

This Workbook Code:

```
'When the workbook is opened, call StartTimer()
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Run "StartTimer"
End Sub

'Detect if the workbook is closed
Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Cancel Saveclose
    Run "StopTimer"
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the error say when it asks you to debug?

Comment: And is the error on the if-statement or the set-statement?

Comment: It yellow highlighted on this line

If wb.Name = GlobalBook.Name Then